# Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state In EF Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stack-overflow

Last night everything was working fine and I woke up this morning to continue working on the project and I am now getting this error

> Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.

The error is pointing at my Entity Framework Context Class, as seen here
[image: Error]

I have never seen this error before, and I am not sure what the issue is, because like I mentioned everything worked last night and now it doesn't.

I have tried Cleaning and Rebuilding the solution, and have also tried restarting Visual Studio, but its not working.
I did some looking around and have seen this error on here but nothing really pertaining to this situation.
My next thought would to be to delete everything and regenerate the EF classes again, but I am hoping that there is another solution other than taking that route?
My apologies if this is a duplicate question, but I have yet to run across this question in regards to the EF Context Class.

**EDIT**

I looked at the references for this and here is a screenshot showing of what I found
[image: References]

The first reference shows this when I hover:
OQOEDAL.cs (19,9)

and the second reference that I hover shows this:
OQOEDAL.cs (19,44)

I know that the first number is the line number but don't know what the second number stands for

Comment: This probably means you have a recursive call. The most common cause is calling a base method from a derived class that has the same signature without the `base.` scope resolution. Check all your derived classes and make sure they don't have this type of code in them.

Comment: @brainlesscoder, I'll check right now.

Comment: @brainlesscoder, I made an edit

Comment: I checked through everything and can't find where it would be recursive

Comment: You must have changed something last night or just before resuming. Try to retrace your steps, even it they seem unrelated to this problem.

Comment: @GertArnold, that's actually a good idea. The only issue now will be trying to remember what I changed last night ;)

Comment: I think you should really rename some of your objects. all your DbContext, the instance of the DbContext, and your connection string are called AdvanceWareJobsEntities. Might be EF tries to evaluate the constructor call rather than the base call in your app.cfg.